# How to get array value that get from checkbox input in Laravel's controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to send 'Date' array from a page to another page through checkbox input for display the data and get more data from database.

I try to dd() the array from input, it's still normal but the data just only show 1 value when I use 'foreach' loop. How do I do?

`<input name="isInvoices[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $date }}">`

```php
   $invoices = $request->input('isInvoices');
   // dd($invoice); It's show array of date
   foreach($invoices as $invoice) {
      dd($invoice); //It's just only 1 value
   }
```

I expected the output to show all value in the array, but the actual output is show 1 value.

Comment: use `echo $invoice;` instead of `dd($invoice);`

Comment: Well of course `$invoice` is one value from the array `$invoices` which is the array that comes from `input('isInvoices')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dd` means `dump` and `die`. Which after the first iteration stops, that's why you see only one item. Try this:

```
foreach($invoices as $invoice) {
    dump($invoice);
}
die;
```

Answer (score 0):

before such would function, you have to have series of checkbox like:

```
this is display series of date values on checkbox. so when you select any dates and submit
foreach($datevalue as $date){
   <input name="isInvoices[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $date }}">
}



//this gets the date value
 $invoices = $request->input('isInvoices');



//this will display all the selected checkboxes 
   foreach($invoices as $invoice) {
      dd($invoice); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

dd() – stands for “Dump and Die”, and it means as soon as loop gets to this command, it will stop executing the program, in this case in first interation. To display all data in *foreach* loop, use *echo* or *print_r()*:

```
foreach($invoices as $invoice) {
    echo $invoice;
}
```

This means that the program will print $invoice for each iteration. Then you can access your data like this:

```
$invoice['value']
```

You can read more about different types of echoing [here](https://laraveldaily.com/echoing-dd-vs-var_dump-vs-print_r/).